# focus on a child element after appending it to a content-editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, appendchild

I have a button that adds a `span` to a content-editable `div`. I want to focus on the `span` so that the user can change the content of it. Actually, this code is a wysiwyg editor so that the user can type some text inside the editable `div` and then press a button to type highlighted text.

Here's my code:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
     var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
     newSpan.classList.add("highlight");
     newSpan.innerHTML = ""; // the span must be empty
     var myDiv = document.getElementById("editable-div");
     myDiv.appendChild(newSpan);
     newSpan.focus();
     // here I expect to be able to change the content of the newSpan, 
     // but I'm still inside the myDiv element.
     // <div id="editable-div" contenteditable="true">
     // <span class="highlight">
     //   I WANT TO BE HERE AFTER APPENDING THE SPAN
     // </span>
     // </div>
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="editable-div" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="btn">Highlight</button>
```

Note: if the span is not empty the code works fine but I want to append an empty span.

Comment: how the user will type inside it? do you need to create a text input?

Comment: no, I want the user change the content of the span. but after appending the span, the user can only change the content of the div element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working snippet for the thing that you are trying to achieve :

```js
var timeout;

$("#btn").click(function() {
  let span = "<span class='highlight' contentEditable='true'></span>";
  $("#editable-div").prop("contentEditable", false);
  $("#editable-div").append(span);
  $("#editable-div span:last-child").focus();


  $("#editable-div span").on("input", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    let breakOf = 1500;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#editable-div").prop("contentEditable", true);
    }, breakOf);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editable-div" contentEditable='true'>
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: your code only work when the content of the span is not empty. if you remove the "new world" from the span, it will not work. actually, if you type new text, it will not be highlighted after appending the span. because you're typing inside the div not the span.

Comment: If you remove the text inside the span tag, it will appear as if it is not present. However, the content will appear when you'd try to type.

Comment: @user6931342 I have added the css so that when the span appears, it is visible to you even after having no text inside.

Comment: the div element must be editable. actually, my code is a wysiwyg editor so that the user can type some text inside the editable div then he click on the button and adds a span to write some highlighted text. your code won't work when the div is editable and the span is empty.

Comment: @user6931342 I have updated the code. Please check if it satisfies you.